# Using Math functions in Entity framework with mysql

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing ASP.NET MVC application and use Mysql with entity framework in it. But I'm having trouble with executing Linq query like this:

```
var place= dbContext.Places.FirstOrDefault(x => Math.Sqrt(x.Lat) > 0);
```

I also tried using SqlFunctions:

```
var place= dbContext.Places.FirstOrDefault(x => SqlFunctions.SquareRoot(x.Lat) > 0);
```

But either way I'm getting  'System.NotSupportedException':

Additional information: The specified method 'System.Nullable`1[System.Double] SquareRoot(System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal])' on the type 'System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlFunctions' cannot be translated into a LINQ to Entities store expression.

Is there any way to use Square root function so that it could be translated into a LINQ to Entities expression?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Entity Framework doesn't support Sqrt function:

[Math Canonical Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738542.aspx) - list of supported functions.

So you can use Math.Pow insted:

```
var place= dbContext.Places.FirstOrDefault(x => Math.Pow(x.Lat,0.5) > 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are trying to perform math.sqrt against the sql database which is not supported.

You would need to either use SQLFunctions or perform a ToList() after dbContext.Places. However, depending on how many places you bring back this would be inefficient.

var place= dbContext.Places.ToList().FirstOrDefault(x => Math.Sqrt(x.Lat) > 0);

Comment: I tried SQLFunctions too, as I mentioned in my question, but didn't help. And ToList would be very slow in my case, I think. freshbm's solution helped.